# Import COM component: Difference c# vs. Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, com, activex, delphi-xe

I need to work with a COM component. Unfortunately its producer explicitly doesn't support Delphi and delivers only C# and VB.NET examples. There is no type library available for that component.

OTOH it's quite straightforward in VS2010 because the respective COM library (WinSig.exe) is listed as a reference.

In the VS2010 IDE this is in "Project - Add reference - COM tab". In Delphi XE I cannot find that entry in "Component - Import Component - ActiveX".

I have inspected the entries in the two IDEs and found that there are some COM components included in the Delphi IDE which are also in the VS IDE but there are a lot of COM components missing in the Delphi IDE.

See for [screenshot file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/10252995/Delphi_VS.jpg) which shows that the first seven COM components are not displayed within the Delphi IDE.

Can one explain why this is so and maybe a help for that specific problem?

Comment: Is the component 64 bit? Your Delphi compiler can only work with 32 bit components.

Comment: The screen shot that you show indicates that you are, in Delphi, using `Import Component | Import ActiveX Control`. Please try to do what @Pol suggested and instead use `Import Component | Import a Type Library`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you checked `Import a Type Library` option in `Import Component` wizard (on the first page)? ActiveX is narrower thing than COM. Also, you can use `Add` button to choose a file if you know library location.

Comment: As mentioned, unfortunately there is no type library for that component available.

Comment: Maybe this is 64 bit issue as David Heffernan said. Did you tried `Add` button?

Comment: @Pol Look at the screenshot added to the question. It's exactly as you suggest in this answer. +1

Comment: The OP posted that his actual problem is that he was using an out-of-process COM/DCOM server EXE and the server EXE was not running, but once it was running, it showed up for him.  I'm putting this comment in for posterity.